# Save & Read using sql

Tags: sql, qt, io, qml

I'm trying to save category names that a user has entered and read them after that by clicking on a button using SQL In Qt Creator, I'm using `QT 5.2.0 Android version, Qt creator 3.0.0`

I have created two functions, one function to save what the user has entered and the other one is reads what the user has entered and displays it on the screen.

Here is my code :

```
function saveCATs() {
    var db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("Cat", "1.0", 
        "Saving Categories File", 1000000);

    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        // Create the database if it doesn't already exist
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Categories(Category TEXT)');

        // tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM Categories WHERE Category ="hello"');

        // Add (another) Category row
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Categories VALUES(?)', [textInput1.text]);
     })
}



function readCATs(){
    var db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("Cat", "1.0", 
        "Saving Categories File", 1000000);
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        // Show all added Categories
        var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Categories');

        var r = ""
        for(var i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) {
            r += rs.rows.item(i).Category +  "\n"
        }
        return r
    })
}
```

`saveCATs()` function is triggered when the user clicks on the button `"submit"` whereas `readCATs()` function is triggered when the user clicks on the button `"Read"`

Here is the code of the buttons:

```
 Rectangle {
           id: rectangle8
           x: 88
           y: 222
           width: 200
           height: 200
           color: "#ffffff"
           opacity: 0
           MouseArea {
               anchors.fill: parent
               onClicked: saveCATs()

           }
       }


Rectangle {
           id: rectangle9
           x: 89
           y: 271
           width: 200
           height: 200
           color: "#ffffff"
           opacity: 0
           MouseArea {
               anchors.fill: parent
               onClicked:{
                   parent.parent.state = "State2"
                   readCATs()

               }
           }
       }
```

But unfortunately this code is not working with me for some reasons that i don't know what they are, Any suggestions

thx

Answer (score 0):

what is your target platform ? as I know :

1. only SQLITE is supported for the Android platform  (to be verified)
2. if not added , add `sql` to your .pro file (QT CREATOR project file) `QT+= sql`
3. try to cook your project in different platforms and see if it's working

Good Luck